# Trying to pull a pin on my Gates control board down to GND without a relay

Tags: transistors, mosfet, relay, esp8266, pullup

I want to pull my [Gates Controller's](https://king-gates.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/STARG8_24_UK.pdf) pin to open the gate down to GND with a esp8266, though I've managed to do this with a relay (shown below)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2mCFN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

but an relay is expensive, overkill and large. So I want to try to minimize the size and expense of the circuit by using either transistors/mosfets, I've used 2n3906 in the configuration below, but I can't seem to get this circuit to working

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpoZJJ.png)</sup>
So is there any other way, or better transistors/mosfet that could help me solve this problem? I'm assuming the pin on the gate is a pull up resistors, that is around 3-5v

Thanks in advance

Manual Gate: https://king-gates.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/STARG8_24_UK.pdf (refer to pages 5, 17)

Answer (score 2):

You should be using a N-channel MOSFET.

Previous answers suggest using a BJT, but BJT will have about 0.6V voltage drop, and the microcontroller will probably read that as a logical 1.

The MOSFET will have almost 0V drop (assuming the current is very small) thus removing that issue.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMnGYN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I was posting an answer about using a MOSFET. Your answer appeared just before I press the Post Your Answer button :) Anyway, it's better to use a logic-level gate MOSFET such as 2N7000 or 2N7002, along with a pull-down resistor of course.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use an NPN not PNP transistor:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should be using an NPN transistor if you are expecting it to work the same as your relay version in your schematic.

You should check how much current is being drawn through the relay contacts when they are closed and the voltage across them when open to ensure you choose a transistor that can take the voltage and current.